# Why does as_tibble(mtcars,rownames = NA) not show the row names? The documentation says that it should

Tags: r, tibble, names, r-rownames

`mtcars` clearly has row names:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

The documentation for `as_tibble` tells me that if I set `rownames = NA` I will get the behavior: `NA: keep row names`. I tried this:

```
> as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = NA)
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
 * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

Clearly, the row names are nowhere to be seen. The default behavior, i.e. `as_tibble(mtcars,rownames = NULL)` (equivalently, `as_tibble(mtcars)`) produces the same output, but with the asterisk above `1` and to the left of `<dbl>` removed.

If I instead use the third and final option for `rownames`, `as_tibble(mtcars,rownames = "String here")`, I finally get to keep the row names:

```
> as_tibble(mtcars,rownames = "String here")
# A tibble: 32 x 12
   `String here`       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4          21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3 Datsun 710         22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6 Valiant            18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7 Duster 360         14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8 Merc 240D          24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9 Merc 230           22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10 Merc 280           19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

But why was that last step necessary? The documentation says that if I set `rownames = NA`, then I will get the behavior: `NA: keep row names`. What about this example prevented `rownames = NA` from keeping the row names, as the documentation claims that it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = NA)` you do keep  the rownames, but they are invisible.

```r
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = NA) %>% 
  rownames_to_column()

#> # A tibble: 32 x 12
#>    rowname       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Mazda RX4    21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2 Mazda RX4 ~  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3 Datsun 710   22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4 Hornet 4 D~  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5 Hornet Spo~  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6 Valiant      18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7 Duster 360   14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8 Merc 240D    24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9 Merc 230     22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10 Merc 280     19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Check the difference in output for `rownames_to_column()` when you don't use `rownames = NA`

```r
as_tibble(mtcars) %>% 
  rownames_to_column()

#> # A tibble: 32 x 12
#>    rowname   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1        21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2 2        21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3 3        22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4 4        21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5 5        18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6 6        18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7 7        14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8 8        24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9 9        22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10 10       19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: "_you do keep the rownames, but they are invisible._" - So in what sense are the rownames kept in this case but not in others? As attributes?